# Avoiding a complete resync of Azure's SQL Data Sync

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

So as a I understand it, if you have an outstanding sync error for more than 40 days Azure's SQL Data Sync forces you to do a fresh upload of your entire database in order to get the service working again.

I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid this as my internet is quite slow and a complete re-sync would take half a week to complete. Is there a way to trick the system into thinking that the error was not present for 40 days and resume it's differential back up after the error has a been corrected?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is correct.  See the MSDN topics http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh667321.aspx#bkmk_databaseoutofdatestatus (for an out-of-date database) and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh667321.aspx#bkmk_sgoutofdatestatus (for an out-of-date sync group).

Answer (score 0):

If it is a database that is out-of-date, you're better off deleting the database then creating it anew, but leaving it empty of data, and adding the empty database to your sync group.  If you merely remove then re-add the populated database to the sync group, on the first sync Data Sync will treat *every row* as a conflict that needs to be resolved (even if the data is unchanged in the row) which adds a lot of time to the initial sync (and may add costs too).  See the topic http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh667328.aspx#InitialSync.